# How to keep auto aspect ratio with PowerBI python custom visual matplotlib plot, when facecolor set to transparent?

Tags: matplotlib, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-python-visual

I have a Python custom visual inside a PowerBI report. Normally, this automatically fills the available space - and set the aspect ratio accordingly. However, when I set a `facecolor` background color (say `None` for a transparent visual, but also any other color), then the visual does not fill the space anymore, just keep the default `matplotlib` aspect ratio. Any ideas on how to force the chart to autofill?

This renders correctly with autofill:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(dataset['Column1'],dataset['Column2'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

But this has the aspect ratio problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(facecolor='red')
plt.plot(dataset['Column1'],dataset['Column2'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can I ask a mod to add `powerbi-python-visual` as a tag? `python-visual` seems to be relating also to the `visual` library in python, which makes it ambiguous. Let's also rename that `python-visual-library` or so.

Comment: I have created the new tag for you.